# R : How to get prob(HR<1) and posterior distribution of the HR in a PFS survival analysis

Tags: r, survival

I performed a survival analysis to compare PFS between 3 groups. I use this code to produce my analysis.

```
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, censor_status) ~ group, data = df)
```

I then use ggsurvplot to plot the survival curves.

I would like to also compute prob(HR < 1) and plot the  posterior distribution of the HR but I couldn't find any information on how to perform such analysis. Anyone could help me here please ?

Thank you

Comment: Try searching Bayesian survival analysis. 'survfit' is maximum likelihood which only has frequentist interpretations.

Comment: If you have 3 groups then there are 3 hazard ratios you might evaluate. Also, the comparison of a hazard ratio against a value of 1 depends on which group is used as the reference. If HR is <1 for `groupB` versus `groupA`, it will be >1 for `groupA` versus `groupB`. The usual frequentist null hypothesis is `HR=1`, independent of choice of reference. Please edit the question to say more about which comparisons you want to make and whether you want to take the Bayesian approach implied by the terminology "posterior distribution of the HR."